# Add last n rows of DataFrame into a new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would to add 4 last numbers of a dataframe and output will be appended in a new column, I have used for loop to do it but it is slower if there are many rows is there a way we can use df.apply(lamda x:) to achieve this.

```
**Sample Input: 
    values
0   10
1   20
2   30
3   40
4   50
5   60

Output:
   values result
0   10     10 
1   20     30   
2   30     60
3   40     100
4   50     140
5   60     180**
```

Comment: df.rolling() is probably what you want

Answer (score 2):

use [`pandas.DataFrame.rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html)

```
>>> df.rolling(4, min_periods=1).sum()
   values
0    10.0
1    30.0
2    60.0
3   100.0
4   140.0
5   180.0
6   220.0
7   260.0
8   300.0
```

Add it together:

```
>>> df.assign(results=df.rolling(4, min_periods=1).sum().astype(int))
   values  results
0      10       10
1      20       30
2      30       60
3      40      100
4      50      140
5      60      180
6      70      220
7      80      260
8      90      300
```